# Span must appear inside circle div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>ooisaj dsaoijdiosa djoisaj doais </span>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
div
{
    margin-left:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nuLkr4q/) with the code.

I want to make the span appear inside the circle. But, I can't achieve it and can't find any question in SO.

Comment: added `padding` demo - https://jsfiddle.net/5nuLkr4q/1/

Comment: shape-inside is what you're looking for, tho it won't be supported for forever

Comment: css3 transform  - https://jsfiddle.net/5nuLkr4q/6/

Answer (score 3):

Using `vertical-align` and `display:table-cell` you can align multiple items in a `<div>`. This is automatic and allows multiple lines to be positioned. *tables* by default vertically center text, so we can take this property and apply it to our `div`. This supports IE8+, basically *every* browser used *(97%)*

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/5nuLkr4q/2/)

---

If you wish for the text to be `left-aligned` you can remove `text-align:center` and add a *little* padding. This causes a problem where the size *(of the div)* increases. To counter this, use `box-sizing: border-box`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/5nuLkr4q/4/)

---

`shape-inside` might be what you want but that is *barely* supported, even in the latest browsers

Learn about it [here](http://hansmuller-webkit.blogspot.com/2012/10/experimental-css-exclusions-shape.html)

---

**CSS3** has *pleanty* of cool share features. Check [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/) out

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this.

```css
div {
    margin-left:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
div span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>ooisaj dsaoijdiosa djoisaj doais </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on **display:table** here, which has a very good browser support:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Apply **display:table-cell, vertical-align: middle, text-align:center** to your span.

Then remember to also apply **display:table**; to your parent container.

```
div {
    margin-left:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    display:table;
}

span{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/5nuLkr4q/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use position:absolute

```
div {
    margin-left:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:20%;
}
```

you should try different percentages

```css
div {
    margin-left:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:20%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>ooisaj dsaoijdiosa djoisaj doais </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    margin-left:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
div span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change display but stay as lose as can to the original "display" defaults.

Assign:

```
div{
    display: table;
}
span{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zlajaa1/p1mr0mhw/)

Comment: your links are broken. Your code isn't formatted, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of centering, that doesn't depend on the knowing the span's height and doesn't use `display:table-cell`. Keep in mind that it works in IE9 and above.

https://jsfiddle.net/5nuLkr4q/7/

```
div {
    margin-left:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative;
}

span{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```